# JBPM execute task multiple times

Tags: task, jbpm, taskservice

In my process, i need to allow a user to execute the same task ( with different params ) multiple times.

Showing TaskService class i observe that there is just complete method.

The complete method set that task to complete and user cannot execute it again.

Is there a solution to that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A task can only be executed once.  However, your process could allow the same task (node) being triggered multiple times, for example use an intermediate signal start event leading to your task, where depending on the data sent alongside the signal, the task will be triggered.  The process could allow retriggering the same task multiple times (during a certain phase of the process for example).